# debugging always give error:line 568, in process_net_command ... NameError: jupyter

Tags: pycharm

my configuration is:

```
ubuntu 18.04
python 3.6
jupyter 4.4.0
pycharm 2019.1.2 build 191.7141.48
```

When starting debugging any python script,pycharm always gives error like this:
[image: error screenshot]

and debugging works actually,but this error message quite annoy,and I have tried to delete /home/alex/.PyCharm2019.1,recreated this configuration files,but problem stays,would you please help to get rid of it,thanks in advance.

Comment: The only available `jupyter` version on PyPI is 1.0.0, could you please clarify what is 4.4.0 exactly?

Comment: @PavelKarateev  typing "jupyter --version" in bash gives 4.4.0